# Showing that every manifold is locally connected

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

I'm asking for some tips on finishing the following proof:

Let $M$ be an $n$-dimensional manifold. To show that $M$ is locally connected, I have to show that every neighborhood of every point $x \in M$ contains a connected neighborhood of $x$. Let $U$ be any neighborhood of $x$ and suppose that $V$ is a neighborhood of $x$ which is homeomorphic to $n$-dimensional open disk $D^n$. Then, if $V \subset U$ we are done as $V$ is connected. But that what if $U \subset V$? Certainly a chart $\varphi$ restricted to $U$ is still a homeomorphism, but my understanding is that we don't know really anything about $U$. Therefore, what if $V$ is the only neighborhood of $x$ that is homeomorphic to $D^n$ and $U$ is some non-connected subset of $V$? How can I finish this proof?

Answer (score 1):

(Note that $V\subseteq U$ and $U\subseteq V$ are not the only two possibilities, as you seem to indicate.) Consider the open set $U\cap V\ni x$. This is an open subset of $V\cong \mathbb R^n$. Then use that $\mathbb R^n$ is locally connected (since $\varepsilon$-balls are connected) to finish the proof.

Comment: Ah, I see; the locally connectedness transfers from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $M$ via the homeomorphism. That is, as $U \cap V$ is open, so is $\varphi\left[U\cap V\right] \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and therefore $\varphi\left[U\cap V\right]$ is locally connected?

Comment: Yep, that's it!